# Bind Json to action parameter ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, json, post, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I'm working on a simple app that uses ASP.NET MVC 5. I had an issue while trying to get a json converted to an entity.

Here is my code:

Entity

```
public class PlayListViewModel
{

    public PlayListViewModel() {
        Tracks = new List<Track>();
    }

    public PlayListViewModel(Dominio.Playlist playList)
    {

        this.Id= playList.Id;
        this.Nombre = playList.Name;

    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Calificacion { get; set; }
    public List<Track> Tracks { get; set; }

    public class Track
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
@model  MyTunes.Models.PlayListViewModel

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Playlist</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Track</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="hidden" id="hdn-track-id" />
            <input type="text" id="input-track" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="button" value="Agregar Track" class="btn btn-default" id="add-track" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table" id="tb_track">
        <tr>
            <th>Lista de Tracks</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" id="create-playlist" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    $("#create-playlist").on('click', function () {

    var playlist = {
        Id : '1',
        Calificacion : '2',
        Nombre : $("#Nombre").val(),
        Tracks: []
    };

    $("td[data-pick='1']").each(function () {
        var idTrack = $(this).attr("data-id");
        playlist.Tracks.push({ Id: idTrack });
    });

    //function PlayListModel() {
    //    var self = this;
    //    self.Nombre = $("#Nombre").val();
    //    self.tracks = [];
    //}

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/Playlist/Create",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(playlist),
            success: function (data) {
                $(".result").html(data);
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json" //"application/json; charset=utf-8"
        });
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Create(PlayListViewModel playlist)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //Of course I have to add some code here
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Json(true);
    }
```

When I run this only the field "Nombre" is mapped as part of the "playlist" object which is received as a parameter of the "Create" action.

I have hard-coded the fields "Id" and "Calificacion" but it is not binding correctly (only show me 0 as they are integers). Also, there is a list of tracks that should be binded but it don't bind either.

I have tried passing the JSON as an object and also with the JSON.stringify method but got not luck.

Any help will be really appreciated (If you prefer to run the code, you can download from here https://github.com/lbendezu/myTunesLux    - visit myTunesLux/MyTunes/DbScripts in order to get the db on )

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, the input #create-playlist was a submit and in JavaScript I was trying to call the click event. In spite of that, the submit event was called and that is why it was binding incorrectly. Now that I changed the type of input to "button" it is working fine.